# Floating point in or out of range?

Tags: c++

Both of these examples below have 8 significand digits, but the first case doesn't give any warning, while the second case does, why?

```
float f1 = 11111111;
float f2 = 99999999;
```

Does the float data type have 7 or 8 significand digits?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Check out [this article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_precision_floating-point_format): The IEEE754 32-bit float has a 24-bit mantissa (cue the omitted leading 1). Now 2<sup>24</sup> is 16'777'216. That means that your first number, 11'111'111, fits nicely, but the second doesn't.

Unfortunately binary isn't the same as decimal, so when discussing precision, most of the time we're really talking about *binary* digits, and the float has 24 significant ones. (There's a shorthand for "binary digit" that escapes me.) The conversion is log<sub>2</sub>10, which is about 3.32, so you get "7.22 decimal digits" out.

Comment: Is the shorthand you're looking for 'bit'?

Comment: Thanks for the article. it seems a little more complicated than I thought it would be.

Comment: @0x5f3759df: That's the one, thanks! user9: Sleep over it, it's actually pretty sensible, and very cleverly designed. For instance, the values of IEEE floats are ordered according to the same ordering as their bit patters, which is brilliant; and +zero is represented by the all-zero bit pattern.